# Find and replace text with jquery, only text no child elements

Tags: jquery, text, replace, find

I want to find and replace text with jquery. I want to change "SKU:" to "art nu."

```
<span itemprop="productID" class="sku_wrapper">
   SKU: 
   <span class="sku">
      5-144
   </span>.
</span>
```

I tried:

```
$(".product_meta>.sku_wrapper:contains('SKU:')" ).text('art nu.');
```

but this delete the child span sku.

Hope someone has a solution...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

since jquery 1.8 you can do it also like this:

```
$(".sku_wrapper").html(function(i,t){
    return t.replace('SKU:','art nu.')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you simply try

```
$(".sku_wrapper" ).each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace('SKU:','art nu.'));
});
```

Comment: Right, dirty keyboard :)