# Find a string in the body of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find a string like `link` and replace it with a `<a href="#link">link</a>`.

Update: After the body is loaded.

Comment: Is there an special element you would look in or it would be the root `html`?

Comment: This question has been asked many times on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205296/find-and-replace-text-with-jquery-only-text-no-child-elements

Comment: the root would be html

Comment: sorry but your question is not clear. why not replace it in your HTML editor using find/replace? if there is a functionality you are looking for, please clarify.

Comment: I have a text and I want to find a certain word and replace it with a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was unclear for me. But the following should work

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/target string/g, "replacement string");
});
```

Comment: Why are you mixing pure JS and jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery answer:

```
<p>link</p>

$('body').html($('body').html().replace('link', '<a href="#link">link</a>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bevanr01/2wttp42j/9/